# How to retrieve certain index in an array from an Angular ng-repeat Directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to get a specific index in an array from an ng-repeat directive.

Now it is printing out the info of all indexes... I just one to print the info  on the second index one for example...

This is my main.js:

```
  app.controller('ProviderController', ['$http', '$scope', function($http, $scope) {
      var provider = this;

    //Get service from API
      $http({
        url: 'http://private-5d90c-kevinhiller.apiary-mock.com/angular_challenge/horror_movies',
        method: "GET",
      }).success(function(data) {
        //process received Data with the processMovie function
         var providers = processMovies(data);
        //process Data with the calculatePercentage function
         var percentages = calculatePercentage(providers, data.length);


         var providerKeys = [];
         for(key in providers) {
          providerKeys.push(key);
         }
         $scope.providerKeys = providerKeys;
         $scope.providers = providers;
         $scope.percentages = percentages;
      })
  }]);


  function processMovies(data) {

    var providers = [],
      movie,
      offer;
    var total = data.length;

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      movie = data[i];
      var movie_id = movie.id;
      for(var j = 0; j < movie.offers.length; j++) {
        offer = movie.offers[j];
        //check if provider_id doesnt exist
        if (typeof providers[offer.provider_id] === 'undefined') {
            providers[offer.provider_id] = {};
            providers[offer.provider_id][movie_id] = movie;
        } else {
            if(!providers[offer.provider_id].hasOwnProperty(movie_id)) {
              providers[offer.provider_id][movie_id] = movie;

            }   
        }

      }  

    }
    return providers;
  }
```

My Html:

```
               <div ng-controller="ProviderController as provider">
                <!-- Include provider controller from Angular-->      
                <div  ng-repeat="providerId in providerKeys">
                    <ul>
                        <li>Provider {{providerId}}: {{percentages[providerId]|number :0 }}%

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div ng-repeat="(provider_id, value) in providers track by $index">
                    <div ng-repeat="movie in value">
                        <p>{{movie.title}} Belongs to provider number: {{provider_id}}</p><br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

As a result i get all movies from all proviers.. how do I say in the Angular directive to just get the ones from provider 2 for example ?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put an `ng-show` or `ng-if` which checks the `$index`.

```
<div ng-repeat="(provider_id, value) in providers track by $index" ng-if="$index==2">
  <div ng-repeat="movie in value">
    <p>{{movie.title}} Belongs to provider number: {{provider_id}}</p><br>
  </div>
</div>
```